# How this aliasing worked

Tags: networking, ip, ip-aliasing

I am trying to do ip aliasing on my ubuntu 12.04 guest and it was not working.

```
host
11.x.11.2

guest 
11.x.11.3
```

guest is using bridge networking with host.

on guest specified

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 11.x.11.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 11.x.11.0
    broadcast 11.x.11.255
    gateway 11.x.11.1

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 11.x.11.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 11.x.11.0
    broadcast 11.x.11.255
    gateway 11.x.11.1
```

after network restart it was showing    **Failed to bring up eth0:0.** .Even reboot also didnt work.

But when changed order in configuration and a network restart fixed the issue

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 11.x.11.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 11.x.11.0
broadcast 11.x.11.255
gateway 11.x.11.1

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 11.x.11.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 11.x.11.0
broadcast 11.x.11.255
gateway 11.x.11.1
```

But what difference this can make,

Comment: you don't need to specify gateway on eth0:0 interface. try to remove it and restart.

Comment: earlier there was no gw on alias,so i tried adding them,but still it didnt work.When it worked i didnt remove it. :)

Answer (score 5):

Interface aliases are seriously deprecated.  The same effect can be achieved with a single stanza and an `ip addr` command (which is what modern ifupdown is using anyway):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 11.x.11.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 11.x.11.0
    broadcast 11.x.11.255
    gateway 11.x.11.1
    up ip addr add 11.x.11.2/24 dev eth0
    # no need for down, ifupdown flush all addresses on stop.
```

Now see the output of `ip addr`, and look how you don't need interface aliases to add several addresses to an interface. And forget about the deprecated `ifconfig`

Comment: wow that is a good trick,i havent even heard of it.
but how can we see signed ip,its not listing in ifconfig.

Comment: @BlueGene: This is already explained in the answer: forget about the old deprecated `ifconfig` from 1999, and use `ip addr` instead. `ip addr` without any options will list the interfaces and addresses.

Comment: You don't need to call `ip addr` from an `up` directive.  It's cleaner to just define a second `iface` stanza for `eth0`: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#iproute2_method